# redshift regex get multiple matches and expand rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working on the URL extraction on AWS Redshift. The URL column looks like this:

```
url                       item     origin
http://B123//ajdsb        apple    US
http://BYHG//B123         banana   UK
http://B325//BF89//BY85   candy    CA
```

The result I want to get is to get the series that starts with B and also expand rows if there are multiple series in a URL.

```
extracted    item     origin
B123         apple    US
BYHG         banana   UK
B123         banana   UK
B325         candy    CA
BF89         candy    CA
BY85         candy    CA
```

My current code is:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '(B[0-9A-Z]{3})') as extracted, item, origin
from data
```

The regex part works well but I have problems with extracting multiple values and expand them to new rows. I tried to use `REGEXP_MATCHES(url, '(B[0-9A-Z]{3})', 'g')` but function regexp_matches does not exist on Redshift...

Comment: at least, I would like to know how can I find multiple matches within a string. It's okay if I get multiple macthes in one row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I use is fairly ugly but achieves the desired results. It involves using `REGEXP_COUNT` to determine the maximum number of matches in a row then joining the resulting table of numbers to a query using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

```
-- Get a table with the count of matches
-- e.g. if one row has 5 matches this query will return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
WITH n_table AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT REGEXP_COUNT(url, '(B[0-9A-Z]{3})') AS n
    FROM data
)
-- Join the previous table to the data table and use n in the REGEXP_SUBSTR call to get the nth match
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '(B[0-9A-Z]{3})', 1, n) AS extracted,
    item,
    origin
FROM data,
     n_table
-- Only keep non-null matches
WHERE n > 0
  AND REGEXP_COUNT(url, '(B[0-9A-Z]{3})') >= N
```

Comment: This solution is really easy to understand! Thanks. I already tested this out on my sampled dataset. It worked well! I'm testing this query on my whole table now.

Comment: Super helpful and easy! Just one point can someone explain `N` in where clause?

Comment: Say an example URL has 3 matches and the URL with the most matches has 5 matches. In this case the `n_table` will hold the values 0,1,2,3,4,5. However, for our example URL (with 3 matches) we only want the n values 1,2,3, hence the where clause.
It might make more sense reversed, `n <= REGEXP_COUNT(url, '(B[0-9A-Z]{3})')`. We're saying for our case with 3 matches (`REGEXP_COUNT` returns 3 for our example URL), we want n to have the values 1,2,3 when producing the output.

Answer (score 1):

**IronFarm**'s answer inspired me, though I wanted to find a solution that didn't require a cross join. Here's what I came up with:

```sql
with 

-- raw data
src as (
  select 
    1 as id,
    'abc def ghi' as stuff
  union all 
  select
    2 as id,
    'qwe rty' as stuff
),

-- for each id, get a series of indexes for
-- each match in the string
match_idxs as (
  select
    id,
    generate_series(1, regexp_count(stuff, '[a-z]{3}')) as idx
  from
    src
)

select 
  src.id,
  match_idxs.idx,
  regexp_substr(src.stuff, '[a-z]{3}', 1, match_idxs.idx) as stuff_match
from 
  src 
  join match_idxs using (id)
order by 
  id, idx
;
```

This yields:

```
 id | idx | stuff_match
----+-----+-------------
  1 |   1 | abc
  1 |   2 | def
  1 |   3 | ghi
  2 |   1 | qwe
  2 |   2 | rty
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Note that `generate_series()` is not actually supported in redshift, and seems to work only on toy examples. Will update my answer when I figure out how to best deal with this.

Comment: yeah... I tested it out on Redshift and `generate_series()` is not working. But it is still great solution for postgresql ^ ^